# Ansible: get all variables in own module?

Tags: python, ansible

Now I use my own module this way:

```
- get_my_data:
    hostvars: '{{ hostvars }}'
```

It uses configuration for all hosts and collects some data.
Can I get `hostvars` inside this module without explicit actions?

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        hostvars=dict(type='dict', required=True),
    ),
    supports_check_mode=True
)
hostvars = module.params['hostvars']
# some exports
result = {'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'my_data': 'test'}}
module.exit_json(**result)
```

Also I export new variables using `ansible_facts` dictionary. How can I export them via `register`?

**Update:** 
Jinja `{{ variables }}` are not replaced inside `hostvars` dict. How can I fix it to give actual vars to module?

**Update 2:**
`hostvars: '{{ hostvars | to_json }}'` helped me to evaluate all the variables

Ansible 2.7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I get hostvars inside this module without explicit actions?

No. You need to explicitly pass in any variables to which you want the module to have access.

> How can I export them via register?

Anything returned via the `exit_json` method will be available in your registered variable.  That is, if you were to have...

```
result = {'changed': False, 'my_data': 'test'}
module.exit_json(**result)
```

...you would find a `my_data` key in your registered variable.

> Jinja {{ variables }} are not replaced inside hostvars dict. How can I fix it to give actual vars to module?

I don't think you're going to be able to do that within your module. With a more complete example in your question, showing exactly what you're trying to do, we might be able to suggest alternative ways of approaching the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have to use `ansible_facts` sub-dictionary to output variables. Also I made an update to my question, can you help with it?

Comment: Thanks. `hostvars: '{{ hostvars | to_json }}'` helped me to evaluate all the variables